# Ошибка при добавлении прелоадера в HaxeFlixel

Tags: haxe

Пытаюсь в *HaxeFlixel* запилить свой прелоадер. Попытался запустить с «пустым» прелоадером, вышла ошибка в `ApplicationMain.hx`.

В нём я обнаружил следующее:

```js
config = {

        build: "4",
        company: "...",
        file: "Danmaku",
        fps: 60,
        name: "Danmaku",
        orientation: "",
        packageName: "com.example.myapp",
        ...
}
```

Я так понял, ошибка именно здесь — `com.example.myapp`.

Прелоадер прописан в `Project.xml`.

Вот код прелоадера:

```hx
package tk.castit.randomia;

import flixel.system.FlxBasePreloader;
import flash.Lib;

/**
* ...
* @author ...
*/
class GamePreloader extends FlxBasePreloader
{

public function new(MinDisplayTime:Float=0, ?AllowedURLs:Array<String>) 
{
    super(MinDisplayTime, ?AllowedURLs);
}
override function create():Void 
{
    this._width = Lib.current.stage.stageWidth;
    this._height = Lib.current.stage.stageHeight;

    var ratio:Float = this._width / 800; 

    super.create();
}   
}
```

Comment: *"вышла ошибка в ApplicationMain.hx"* -- какая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Project.xml` нужно приписывать полный путь к прелоадеру. В данном случае — `domain.ui.GamePreloader"`